# Google Maps website in Android OS

Tags: android, google-maps

I have built a website which involves Google Map API and I want to view that page with my Android OS phone, but when I open the page it states that I need Google Map API key, which is there because I can see the map in my PC. I tried to generate an Android API key but I don't know where to put that code, because it's in XML and sources in the Internet talk only about making an application for Android, which is not what I want.
What must I do if I want my website to show my made Google Map? Has anyone got this problem ever? Is it even possible to view Google Maps from Android OS without it being inside a specific application?

Answer (score 0):

you just put this in you xml

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:apiKey="example_Maps_ApiKey_String" // put your map api key
 />
```

Comment: What should I name the XML? I only have a PHP, HTML, CSS and JS files

Comment: I have no idea about web application. this is for mobile application. you can visit this link [Google Map Api FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html) you will get your answers. Thanks

Comment: So, apparently there is no way for android OS to see google maps, unless it's made as an app?

Answer (score 0):

Use following link, where 50 is your latitude and 10 is your longitude: http://maps.google.com/maps?&daddr=50,10